# Poor query planning in Postgres 10

Tags: postgresql, optimization, execution-plan, performance, postgresql-performance

The query planner in Postgres10 seems to be ignoring the fact that my tables are clustered. I have to explicitly put "hints" in my query to have it perform the correct type of join.

Here's my situation...

I have 3 tables: l_str, l_dbl, and l_data. The tables are first created, then populated, then clustered, then vacuum/analyzed. After that, they're only ever read from (never written to).

```
-- Create tables
CREATE TABLE L_STR(
  KEY                  VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
  NAME                 VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
  VAL                  VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(KEY, NAME)
);
CREATE TABLE L_DBL(
  KEY                  VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
  NAME                 VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
  VAL                  DOUBLE PRECISION,
  PRIMARY KEY(KEY, NAME)
);
CREATE TABLE L_DATA(
  KEY                   VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
  DATA_BLOCK            BYTEA               NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(KEY)
);

-- Insert rows
...

-- Cluster tables and run analyze
CREATE INDEX DATA_IDX ON L_DATA(KEY);
CLUSTER L_DATA USING DATA_IDX;
VACUUM ANALYZE L_DATA;

CREATE INDEX STR_IDX ON L_STR(NAME, VAL, KEY);
CLUSTER L_STR USING STR_IDX;
VACUUM ANALYZE L_STR;

CREATE INDEX DBL_IDX ON L_DBL(NAME, VAL, KEY); 
CLUSTER L_DBL USING DBL_IDX;
VACUUM ANALYZE L_DBL;
```

pg_stats for my tables after this process...

```
SELECT tablename, attname, correlation FROM ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

```
| tablename |  attname   | correlation  |
|-----------|------------|--------------|
| l_data    | data_block | -0.011323823 |
| l_data    | key        |          1.0 |
| l_dbl     | name       |          1.0 |
| l_dbl     | key        |  -0.10221779 |
| l_dbl     | val        |   0.72073925 |
| l_str     | name       |          1.0 |
| l_str     | key        |  0.038144425 |
| l_str     | val        |  -0.27145308 |
```

Given that my tables are clustered, I would expect the query planner to take that information into account when choosing what type of join to do. Take the following example...

```
EXPLAIN (analyze true, buffers true, timing true)
SELECT x0.* FROM
  l_data x0
    INNER JOIN
  (SELECT KEY FROM l_str WHERE name='data_type' and val='metatranscriptomics') x1
    ON x0.KEY = x1.KEY;
```

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..130.30 rows=69 width=821) (actual time=0.235..6.210 rows=835 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=2512 read=11
  ->  Index Only Scan using str_idx on l_str  (cost=0.42..2.90 rows=69 width=22) (actual time=0.212..0.568 rows=835 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((name = 'data_type'::text) AND (val = 'metatranscriptomics'::text))
        Heap Fetches: 0
        Buffers: shared hit=1 read=11
  ->  Index Scan using data_idx on l_data x0  (cost=0.28..1.85 rows=1 width=821) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=835)
        Index Cond: ((key)::text = (l_str.key)::text)
        Buffers: shared hit=2511
Planning time: 1.073 ms
Execution time: 6.271 ms
```

Given the clustering I've applied to my tables, I expected the above query to be performed using a merge join instead of a nested loop. The first input into the inner join (table l_data) is ordered by KEY. The second input into the inner join should also be ordered by KEY (table l_str is clustered on name,val,key).

I was able to get the query planner to perform a merge join by shoving an "ORDER BY" for l_data...

```
EXPLAIN (analyze true, buffers true, timing true)
   SELECT x0.* FROM
     (SELECT * FROM public.l_data ORDER BY KEY) x0
       INNER JOIN
     (SELECT KEY FROM public.l_str WHERE name='data_type' and val='metatranscriptomics') x1
       ON x0.KEY = x1.KEY;
```

```
Merge Join  (cost=0.84..805.26 rows=69 width=821) (actual time=0.395..4.124 rows=835 loops=1)
  Merge Cond: ((l_data.key)::text = (str_idx.key)::text)
  Buffers: shared hit=657
  ->  Index Scan using data_idx on l_data  (cost=0.28..732.48 rows=5533 width=821) (actual time=0.005..1.405 rows=5533 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=645
  ->  Index Only Scan using l_str on str_idx  (cost=0.42..2.90 rows=69 width=22) (actual time=0.021..0.179 rows=835 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((name = 'data_type'::text) AND (val = 'metatranscriptomics'::text))
        Heap Fetches: 0
        Buffers: shared hit=12
Planning time: 0.589 ms
Execution time: 4.161 ms
```

It doesn't really make sense to do this because l_data's should already be physically ordered by KEY. Either way, you can see how much better the query performs: 657 vs 2512 hits / 4.1ms vs 6.2ms.

Is there anyway to get Postgres's query planner to take physical table ordering into account (e.g. query hints, config options, etc..)?

Just in case it matters: I'm using Postgres 10.5 on a 4 core Windows10 machine with a SSD.

Here's my configuration:

```
max_connections = 20
shared_buffers = 512MB
effective_cache_size = 4608MB
maintenance_work_mem = 768MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 500
random_page_cost = 1.1
work_mem = 24029kB
min_wal_size = 4GB
max_wal_size = 8GB
max_worker_processes = 4
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 2
max_parallel_workers = 4
```

Comment: Trying to optimize a query that runs under 100ms makes no sense.
Optimization is a delicate process and the first rule of optimization is : don't. (The second rule is : don't now.)

My advice would be to optimize what's need to be optimized and a 6 (or 4) ms query don't need optimization. But maybe your real problem is on a production server when that query is much slower ?